# By jquery set css left for multiple div?

Tags: jquery, css

Hi i want to apply css `left` property in `%` for multiple div how will i do . i have tried below code

**HTML**

```
<div class="inner-nav blue" rel="blue"> 
    <a href="#" style="display: block; left: 0%;">
       Text1 <br>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="inner-nav blue" rel="blue"> 
   <a href="#" style="display: block; left: 0%;">
       Text2 <br>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="inner-nav blue" rel="blue"> 
   <a href="#" style="display: block; left: 0%;">
      Text3 <br>
   </a>
</div>
<div class="inner-nav blue" rel="blue"> 
   <a href="#" style="display: block; left: 0%;">
      Text4 <br>
   </a>
</div>
```

**In JS**

```
$(".inner-nav").each(function(){                                                       
      $(this).find("a:first").css("left", function( index ) {
         var f= index*25;
             f=f+"%";                                                                    
        return  f;
      });         
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you are defining `index` in the wrong place. You are getting the `index` of the element that `css()` is being called on, but it will always be the first in the set, so `index` will always be 0:

```
$(".inner-nav").each(function (index) {
    $(this).find("a:first").css("left", function () {
        var f = index * 25;
        f = f + "%";
        return f;
    });
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLLMj/1/)

The `each()` loop isn't needed. Many jQuery methods, including `css()` handle looping through each element matched to the selector on it's own:

```
$(".inner-nav").find("a:first").css("left", function( index ) {
    var f= index*25;
    f=f+"%";                                                                    
    return f;
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GLLMj/)

Comment: what's difference from the OP?

Comment: thanks @oGeez its works for me and thanks for the knowledge about index which i am using on my own code can you give me a link by which i can understand in depth and if you can explain me then it would be a like a party for me :)

Comment: [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/) and [`css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is index of anchor which is always `0` so `0%` is applied to each anchor so you can try this:

```
$(".inner-nav").each(function () {
  var idx = $(this).index(); // get the div's index
  $(this).find("a:first").css("left", function (index) {
    var f = idx * 25; // and use it here.
    f = f + "%";
    return f;
  });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2gkDK/)

---

To simplify this you can use it:

```
$(".inner-nav").each(function (idx) {
    $(this).find("a:first").css("left", idx * 25 + "%");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not passed index as function attribute. Due to which its not define inside loop.also index is 0 based here. so first anchor of first div will have 0% left. Try this:

```
 $(".inner-nav").each(function(index){                                                       
                  $(this).find("a:first").css("left",index*25+'%');
 });
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R2DzV/38/)**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".inner-nav").each(function (i) {
    var inn = $(this).index();
    var f = parseInt(inn) * 25;
    var cf = f + "%";
    $(this).find("a:first").css("left", cf);
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/rF7LR/5/)